# How can I use named parameters AND prevent the default constructor from being used?

Tags: groovy

I'm confused about how to accomplish this in the cleanest most Groovy way, but I can't figure out how to do it at all first

I just want to force that when a class is created all its constructor args be set:

```
class MyClass {
  String paramOne
  String paramTwo

  MyClass(paramOne, paramTwo) throws Exception {
    this.paramOne = paramOne
    this.paramTwo = paramTwo
  }

}

// I want to throw an error if all the constructor args arent set
// This doesnt throw an error
MyClass blah = new MyClass()
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494229/how-to-prevent-default-constructor-from-being-used ... as you can reed, null will be used if no parameters are provided, so in your constructor you should check the value of thee params and throw an exception

Comment: could you provide an example of what that would look like for MyClass?

Comment: Is there a way I can use named parameter and prevent the default constructor for being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question from the comment:

> Is there a way I can use named parameter and prevent the default constructor for being used?

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class A{
    String p1
    int p2
    
    A(Map params=null){
        assert params:"at least one parameter is required for ${this.getClass()}"
        A.metaClass.setProperties(this,params)
        //validate params...
        assert p1:'`p1` couldn\'t be empty'
    }
}

A a=new A(p1:111,p2:222)
println a

new A() // <<<--- this throws exception
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy "I just want to force that when a class is created all its constructor args be set".  Is the idea to add an `assert` for every property?

Answer (score 0):

> // This doesnt throw an error
> MyClass blah = new MyClass()

That does not make sense.  That should throw an error.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888.

[app/src/main/groovy/red888/MyClass.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888/blob/8dfb5e8f3a033549d518f2b7182209621ff401f7/app/src/main/groovy/red888/MyClass.groovy)

```
package red888

class MyClass {
    String paramOne
    String paramTwo

    MyClass(paramOne, paramTwo) throws Exception {
        this.paramOne = paramOne
        this.paramTwo = paramTwo
    }

}
```

[app/src/main/groovy/red888/App.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888/blob/8dfb5e8f3a033549d518f2b7182209621ff401f7/app/src/main/groovy/red888/App.groovy)

```
package red888

class App {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        //  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: red888.MyClass()
        MyClass blah = new MyClass()
    }
}
```

That throws the expected exception.

```
~ $ mkdir demo
~ $ cd demo
demo $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/red888.git
Cloning into 'red888'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 25, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 25 (delta 3), reused 25 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (25/25), 60.11 KiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
demo $ 
demo $ cd red888
red888 (main)$ 
red888 (main)$ ./gradlew run

> Task :app:run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: red888.MyClass()
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1845)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1615)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:268)
        at red888.App.main(App.groovy:6)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: If you are wanting `new MyClass()` to be a compilation error instead of a runtime error, you can mark the code that is invoking that with `@CompileStatic` and then the code won't even compile.